# Java is Reading Excel column Header which required to be exclude

Tags: java

My code is running fine however it is displaying column headers (Username, password)... How can i make change to my code which can accept only values and not header....

```
public Object [][] readExcel() throws BiffException,IOException
{ 
//Create file instance

File f = new File("T:/SeleniuminputFiles/input1.xls");
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
Sheet s = w.getSheet("Sheet1");
int rows = s.getRows();
int column =s.getColumns();

String inputData [][] = new String [rows][column];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j <column; j++) {
        Cell c = s.getCell(j, i);
        inputData[i][j] = c.getContents();
        System.out.println(inputData[i][j]);
    }
}
return inputData;
}
```

My Excel file is given below and in output i do not want column headers username, password to be read out.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: At a guess, start `i` from 1. You'll generally get more luck if you include source as text rather than images, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added the code. i tried with i = 1 but it is giving me output  with the username, password. How can i skip the 1st row as header for columns and start with 2nd row as actual data

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in your for loop. It should work.

```
for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j <column; j++) {
        Cell c = s.getCell(i, j);
        inputData[i-1][j] = c.getContents();
        System.out.println(inputData[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Shubham, sorry for late response as i was away. the issue remain same as it is taking null values now. with blank username and blank password.

Comment: Hi Sushat, I have updated my answer, changed inputData[i][j] to inputData[i-1][j], please execute and let me know

Answer (score -1):

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath1));
br.skip(1);

Comment: Happens to me too, not reading the question carefully: not text reading (and storing to Excel) but Excel reading. Delete your own answer to save on negative points.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.